# How to use Ember addons in Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Is there a good way to use ember addons in Rails app? There are a lot of separated js(es6) files per addon. The best way for me is to get .coffee and .hbs files, that I can include in my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an Ember application embedded inside a Ruby on Rails application I suggest updating your Ember infrastruture to [ember-cli-rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails), which I believe enables you to use addons directly.